# How to Save uploaded file (any file) to SQL AZure table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

How to Save uploaded file (any file) to SQL AZure table?

Comment: why do you prefer that, there's azure blob storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the files in varbinary(max) fields and stream them to and from SQL Azure.

For a code sample see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/17/streaming-blobs-to-and-from-sql-azure.aspx